# Initial charge in parallel plate capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, charge, capacitance

Two capacitors $C_1$ and $C_2$ (where $C_1 > C_2$) are charged to the same initial potential difference $\Delta V_i$. The charged capacitors are removed from the battery, and their plates are connected with opposite polarity. The switches S1 and S2 are then closed. Find the final potential difference $\Delta V_f$ between $a$ and $b$ after the switches are closed as in figure down below.
[image]

The solution finds the initial charge $Q_i = Q_{1i}+Q_{2i} = C_1 \Delta V_i -C_2 \Delta V_i = (C_1 - C_2) \Delta V_i$.
I don't understand why is there a negative sign for $Q_{2i}$. Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacitor plates in figure 26.12(a) are connected in a way that the positive plate of one capacitor is connected by a wire to the *negative* plate of the other capacitor (It's written in your question, the plates are connected with *opposite polarity*). Because there is no battery or an external source of voltage, the electrons from the negative plate neutralize a part of the positive charge, so the charges would be balanced, and hence lower, which is why the negative sign is used for $Q_{2i}$

Hope this helps

Comment: Since the figure is symmetrical, why don't we put a negative sign for $Q_{1i}$ instead of $Q_{2i}$ ? Does the initial charge $Q_i$ have to be strictly positive ?

Comment: You absolutely can. However, note that $C_1$ > $C_2$ necesarily implies $Q_1$ > $Q_2$ because the voltages are the same, so the final charge that remains needs to be a positive one ($Q_1 -  Q_2$)